# pine script error when change version 2 to 4

Tags: pine-script

I have a error when I change pine script version 2 to 4

line 17: Undeclared identifier '_direction';

line 18: Variable '_direction' is not found in scope 'anonym_function_0', cannot register side

Code is below

```
    //@version=4
    study(title='ZigZag PA Strategy V4 ALERT')
    useHA = input(false, title='Use Heikken Ashi Candles')
    useAltTF = input(true, title='Use Alt Timeframe')
    tf = input('30', title='Alt Timeframe')
    showPatterns = input(true, title='Show Patterns')
    showFib0000 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.000:',defval=true)
    showFib0236 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.236:',defval=true)
    showFib0382 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.382:',defval=true)
    showFib0500 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.500:', defval=true)
    showFib0618 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.618:', defval=true)
    showFib0764 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 0.764:', defval=true)
    showFib1000 = input(title='Display Fibonacci 1.000:', defval=true)
    zigzag() =>
        _isUp = close >= open
        _isDown = close <= open
        _direction = _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
        _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? lowest(2) : na

    _ticker = useHA ? heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) : syminfo.tickerid
    sz = useAltTF ? (change(time(tf)) != 0 ? security(_ticker, tf, zigzag()) : na) : zigzag()
```

How can I fix it?

Plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

In v4, variables require declaration before referring to them in the right part of an assignment. Compare results with v2 carefully before using:

```
zigzag() =>
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _direction = 0
    _direction := _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
    _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? lowest(2) : na
```